# Access VBA SQL Run-time error '3075' Syntax error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run this code but it gives me the error message:

> Run-time error '3075'; "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression"

How should I fix this error?

I would like insert *CellNumber* that is in *table1* but not in *Variable* table into *ERROR* table with *DateTime*, string, and *CellNumber*

```vb
Dim sqlstr As String

sqlstr = "SELECT CellNumber FROM table1 WHERE CellNumber NOT IN (SELECT CellNumber FROM Variable)"

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO ERROR ([DateTime], RowNum, Error) SELECT Now(), 'string' as RowNum, CellNumber FROM(" & sqlstr & ")"
```

Comment: Also, would it be better to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN? or is it similar in terms of speed?

Comment: THe resultant SQL you are trying to run is :

INSERT INTO ERROR ([DateTime], RowNum, Error) SELECT Now(), 'string' as RowNum, CellNumber FROM(SELECT CellNumber FROM table1 WHERE CellNumber NOT IN (SELECT CellNumber FROM Variable))
I think your problem lies in 
", CellNumber FROM(SELECT CellNumber FROM "

Comment: SO all you want to do is find all the cellnumbers in table1 that do not exist in Variable table? And then insert them into Error table?

Comment: No need to wrap the above `SELECT` in parentheses within below's `FROM` as query expects a table alias. And add space after `FROM`. Also, escape [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE).

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim sqlstr As String
    sqlstr = "INSERT INTO Error ( [DateTime],RowNum, Error ) " & _
             "SELECT Now() , 'String' , table1.cellnumber FROM table1 " & _
             "LEFT JOIN Variable ON table1.cellnumber = Variable.cellnumber " & _
             "WHERE  Variable.cellnumber Is Null"
    currentdb.execute sqlstr, dbfailonerror
```

That's how I would do it

**Edit------**
I would like to add for posterity a few comments:

1. I would personally set my DateTime stamp field with a default value of `Now()` and omit it from my sql altogether...All new records would get time-stamped with less room for error.

> ```
> Dim sqlstr As String
>         sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tblError ( StringField, CellNumber ) " & _
>                  "SELECT 'String' , table1.cellnumber FROM table1 " & _
>                  "LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cellnumber = table2.cellnumber " & _
>                  "WHERE  table2.cellnumber Is Null"
>         currentdb.execute sqlstr, dbfailonerror
> ```

2. I would never use `DateTime`, `Error`, or `Variable` as a table or field name, because even if access can deal with it (by delimiting reserved names `[DateTime]`, for Instance), it can be confusing and misleading when trying to troubleshoot your code and sql.

Comment: As a side note: I would personally avoid using `error` and `DateTime` as field or table names

Comment: @Parfait I agree. I figured he was simply using some generic names here for the purpose of getting his SQL right.